# Image layer in open layers

Tags: openlayers

I have to create a image layer using `OpenLayers.Layer.Image` of openlayers. Image is a static image for time being. The image represents the entire area which I want to capture. I have the the latitude & longitude of the corner point of the area that the image represents. When I put these lat lon as bounds the image gets stretched.

I would like to know how to show static image with bounds defined, and once I start zooming the image will zoom.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is kind of complicated (sorry).

In order to to have an image layer that behaves as a map, which can be zoomed in and out, you need to convert the image into a map.

You can use the *georeference-plugin* for QGIS to geo-reference your image and something like [Maptiler](http://www.maptiler.org/) to create tiles from your referenced image. When you have the properly created map tiles you can use the Opanlayers TMS layer to display the data. (or just serve it as a WMS with Geoserver)

Hope this helps, or at least gives you something to Goole for!

Answer (score 1):

OpenLayers.Layer.Image should be fine for that purpose:
http://jsfiddle.net/cv3uC/4/
(You have to play with different map properties to get desired initial extent, number of zoom levels etc).

If your image gets stretched, bounds is probably uncorrect. Calculate width / height ratio both for your image and for bounds. They should be same.

```
var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(10, 10, 260, 297);
var size = new OpenLayers.Size(250, 287);

alert(
    'Image ratio: ' + 
    (size.w / size.h).toString() +
    ' Bounds ratio: ' +
    (bounds.getWidth() / bounds.getHeight()).toString()
);
```